# Оператор BETWEEN в T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возможно ли как-то через оператор BETWEEN выбрать все имена из колонки FirstName, но у которых 3-я буква в имени из определенного диапазона, например, c и f? С первой буквой все понятно:

```
WHERE FirstName BETWEEN 'c' AND 'f'
```

А как сделать не для первой - непонятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
where SUBSTRING(FirstName,3,1) between 'c' and 'f'
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще использовать [like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) для этих целей ([пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db/60)):

```
where FirstName like '__[c-f]%'
```